# Vue.js - Binding array with multiple keys with same name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass multiple values through Vue.js, under the same key name to keep it dynamic.

This is my code:

`Input.vue`:

```
<search-popover :fields="[{
 names: ['Title1', 'value1'],
 names: ['Title2', 'value2'],
}]"></search-popover>
```

Now, in my `Popover.vue` file, I only get the **last** element of the `:fields`:

```
<ul v-for="field in fields">
    <li>
       <h5>{{ field.names[0] }}</h5>
       {{ values[field.names[1]]}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Will output:

```
Title2
Value2
```

How can I do, so I can set the values of `:fields` dynamically, so I can access the array in my `v-for`, and it will output:

```
Title1
Value1

Title2
Value2
```

Comment: a syntax problem `:fields="[{
 names: ['Title1', 'value1'],
 names: ['Title2', 'value2'],
}]"`, i think you are actually trying to do `:fields="[
 { names: ['Title1', 'value1'] }, 
 { names: ['Title2', 'value2'] },
]"`

Comment: I don't think that you can assign two times the same key in a javascript object. 
const object = {
 foo: 'one',
        foo: 'two'
}
console.log(object) => {foo: 'two'}

Comment: @Hammerbot Any other way I can dynamically assign multiple values to the component directly?

Comment: You should try what @JacobGoh wrote: `:fields="[ { names: ['Title1', 'value1'] }, { names: ['Title2', 'value2'] }, ]"`

Comment: Ah, didn't see your comment Jacob! This works like a charm. Please submit it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in

```
:fields="[{
 names: ['Title1', 'value1'],
 names: ['Title2', 'value2'],
}]"
```

where you are creating 1 array containing only 1 object.

(when an object has duplicated properties, the latter one is used. Therefore, `{ names: ['Title1', 'value1'], names: ['Title2', 'value2'], }` is equilavant to `{ names: ['Title2', 'value2'], }`)

What you want is probably 1 array containing 2 objects, which should be

```
:fields="[ 
    { names: ['Title1', 'value1'] }, 
    { names: ['Title2', 'value2'] }, 
]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to have the same key name more than once or the last key will be the only one display.

Correctly iterating through `names` must be with its own object. Like this:

```
:fields = "[
  { names: ['Title1', 'value1'] }, 
  { names: ['Title2', 'value2'] }
]"
```

As written by [@jacobgoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5599288/jacob-goh)